# How to inform GDB via a stub that its asumptions on watchpoint values should be invalidated?

Tags: debugging, gdb, emulation

I am trying to setup a reverse engineering environment with a GBA emulator called mgba and it has a GDB stub which has enough features to support basic commands such as read/write watchpoints.

However, like many other console emulators, it supports savestates which are a way for the emulator to save and restore completely its state (such as memory, CPU, etc...). Because of this, let's say I add a write (not read/write) watchpoint somewhere and the emulator eventually writes to it; GDB will read the new value and determine that there was a change so it will acknowledge the watchpoint and take control back from the inferior. However, let's say that I later decide to load a savestate and that the emulator writes to this value again, but it's the same value as before. Now GDB will read the new value, think it hasn't changed and refuse to take control, it will simply tell the inferior to continue.

The problem is GDB doesn't know after the restore that the value changed externally to the game's code so it thinks there was no change. To me, it seems there would be 2 ways to fix this issue:

1: Allow me to tell GDB to break on ANY write to this address no matter if the value changed or not (this would be ideal, but I couldn't find a way to do this other than awatch which isn't what I want here)

2: Allow me to tell GDB via the stub that its assumptions are wrong: it should reread its watchpoints and overwrite the values that it had saved before so that when it triggers again, GDB would know.

2 seems to be the most promising option, but I am not aware on how to do this besides sending a ctrl+c and then resuming (since it seems GDB removes all its watchpoints on stop and restores them on resume which forces it to reread the value). That solution isn't ideal because I don't want the emulation to stay paused.

Would there be a way to inform GDB of the event via the stub, but have GDB let the emulation continue as normal?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way: you have the stub send S05 or T05, but nothing more because if you send T05watch with the address, GDB will figure out you broke because of the watchpoint and do the old vs new logic, but by actually just sending a generic SIGTRAP, GDB will happily let the inferior stops, hopefully this helps someone.